# Prove that $n\cdot [a]=[a+ \sqrt{2}n]$ is an action of $Z$ on the set $S$.

Tags: group-theory

Set $S=R/Z=\{[a]∶a \in R \}.$  Prove that $n\cdot [a]=[a+ \sqrt{2}n]$ is an action of $Z$ on the set $S$.

I only really need help with showing the associativity part. I showed it was a function already and that $0 \times [a] = [a + \sqrt{2} \times 0] = [a].$ I am having trouble writing the rest out.

Comment: I think you have a typo.

Comment: yes i do thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

$(n+m)\cdot [a]=[a+\sqrt{2}\times (n+m)]=[a+\sqrt{2}\times m+\sqrt{2}\times n]=n\cdot [a+\sqrt{2}\times m]$

Comment: I see where I went wrong thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, by the definition you are given, it is $n\cdot [a] \in S$, and thence we have indeed a map $\mathcal{A}\colon\mathbb{Z}\times S \to S$.

Secondly:

- $0\cdot [a]=[a+\sqrt{2}\times 0]=[a], \space\forall [a]\in S$;
- $m\cdot (n\cdot [a])=m\cdot [a+\sqrt{2}n]=[a+\sqrt{2}n+\sqrt{2}m]=[a+\sqrt{2}(m+n)]=(m+n)\cdot[a], \space\forall m,n\in\mathbb{Z}, \forall [a]\in S$

Therefore, $\mathcal{A}$ is indeed an action.